# How to make video without hd (60fps) effect in 4K

Tags: premiere, filming, iphone

I’m new to video production so please help me to understand one thing that I can’t find out.

Some videos in 4k or even 1080p don’t have this effect when the picture is super real and some videos have it. I mean for example when I download film to my new 4K TV in 1080p it can be more cinematic and another film more like (60fps) I want to make clips and short films without this effect. I shoot on iPhone X. What adobe premier settings should I set for videos to have more cinematic picture then “super-real”.
Many thanks!!

Comment: This question is very confusing. Please help us understand what you are trying to accomplish so that we can help you both improve the question and find an answer. Examples of what you consider “super-real” and “cinematic” might help, but those are often very subjective traits.  Also, you understand that frame rate and resolution are independent of each other, correct? A 1920x1080 video can be 60, 30, 24, or any other rate (FPS), and so can a 3840x2160 (UHD 4K) video.

Comment: Are you asking about how lower resolution footage sometimes looks different on your 4K television? It sounds like you might be referring to the motion smoothing effect that many modern televisions have, but the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather confusing, but I'm going to assume you want to avoid smooth high frame rate footage

To do this, set your iPhone X to record at 24fps (or 30, if 24 is not available) and use the same frame rate (24/30fps) in Adobe Premiere.

It is important to make sure your iPhone X is also recording at the correct frame rate, as recording in 60fps but editing at 24fps will lead to choppy-looking footage and might cause other sorts of trouble